# How to delete custom workflow definition in liferay?

Tags: java, liferay

I have made a custom workflow definition in liferay but don't know how to delete it. I tried to remove the definition from control panel but it is showing error-
`com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowException:"Cannot delete incomplete workflow definition`". So how to remove it manually from folder. Where do they get stored?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer...I deleted the definition from database table named "kaleodefinition"